# How to pass multiple query-set in another class function

Tags: python, django

Let suppose I have some model

```
class Testmodel1():
   amount = models.IntegerField(null=True)
   contact = models.CharField()
class Testmodel2():
  price = models.ForeignKey(Testmodel1, null=True)
```

Now I am using django ORM and apply a query like:

```
objs = Testmodel2.objects.filter(price__amount=123)
```

and it is returning `n` number of `obj` in any case like `(obj1, obj2,..)` ,

also I have written a another function in another class which is handling these `obj` and performing some other task, like-

`Class SentMail():
    def sending_mail(self, price_obj):
           """performing some task """`

SO, currently I am doing like

```
for obj in objs:
    sentmail().sending_mail(obj)
```

Is there any other better way to do this to make it better, I tried to find a good way, but don't get.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems fine to me. You could, given your snippet, instantiate a `SentMail` instance once before the loop and reuse it, but unless you can collect recipients and send one mail to them all, I don't see much improvement.

Comment: This is all a bit vague. One thing I would ask is why SentMail needs to be a class? Why can't you just have `sending_mail` as a standalone function? Or a method on the model itself?

Comment: `sentMail` for class I just gave the name as example, In real there is a class and function which is handling `objs` for performing some `periodic` task

Comment: It depends on the real nature of your task an what 'sending_mail' is doing if it can be improved / batched. If it can't this is fine.